# Is it possible to build a list from a carriage return separated string?

Tags: flutter, dart

### Background

I have the following string:

```dart
var MyString = 'Test1⏎Test2⏎Test3⏎Test4'
```

`⏎` = line feed = `\n`

### What I'm trying to do

- I want to create a `List` which is a list of lines. Basically every item that is followed by a `\n` would become an entry in the list.
- I want the base string `MyString` to become shortened to reflect what pieces of the string have been moved to the `List`
- The reason I want to leave a residual `MyString` is that new data might come in later that might be considered part of the same line, so I do not want to commit the data to the `List` until there is a carriage return seen

### What the result of all this would be

So in my above example, only `Test1` `Test2` `Test3` are followed by `\n` but not `Test4`

Output `List` would be:  `[Test1, Test2, Test3]`

`MyString` would become: `Test4`

#### What I've tried and failed with

I tried using `LineSplitter` but it seems to want to take `Test4` as a separate entry as well

```dart
final lines = const LineSplitter().convert(MyString);
for (final daLine in lines) {
  MyList.add(daLine);
}
```

And it creates `[Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4]`

Comment: FYI, carriage return is `\r`. `\n` is a linefeed (or usually represents a "newline").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution would be to just `.removeLast()` on the list that you split.

```dart
String text = 'Test1\nTest2\nTest3\nTest4';

List<String> list = text.split('\n');
text = list.removeLast();

print(list); // [Test1, Test2, Test3]
print(text); // Test4
```

Comment: nit: I think it's conceptually the same approach, but neater and just a hair more efficient, to build the list and then pop the last entry. (a sublist instead of substring, if you will :))

Comment: @Simone You're correct. That is a better approach if there is no other constraint OP hasn't mentioned.

Comment: @Simone but if I just made a list how would you know if that very last entry has a \n with it or not? Once these entries are in the list doesn't that info get lost?

Comment: @Mark The `split('\n')` method breaks the string at every `\n`, meaning that the last entry will be everything that follows the last `\n` already, so you just need to set the `text` variable to that, using `removeLast()`. If the last entry has a `\n` with it, the list will have a **blank entry (empty string) at the end**, caused by the split method, which will get removed by `removeLast()` anyways.

Comment: @Suporte01 Ah ok I get you guys.  TBH what you first provided is working like a charm, so Im just going to stay with this, and revisit this concept if I see it breaking with more complex strings.  Thanks!!!

Comment: LineSplitter works no matter what the newline character is (`\n`, `\r`, etc) so that is the kind of "more complex string" that will break without it. It sounds like you should try to get a basic version working and then return to this detail, though.

Answer (score 0):

To me you are combining two questions. Every language I know has built-in ways to split a string on a char, including newline chars. The distinct thing you want is a split function that doesn't include the last entry.

You may be combining your answers as well :) Is there some resource constraint or streamed input that prevents you from just building the list, then popping off the final entry?

If yes:
I think you have to build your own split. Look at the implementation code for LineSplitter(), and make something similar except which leaves the final entry.

If no:
simply call

```
MyString = MyList.removeLast();
```

after your for-loop.